# MediaRecorder timeslice segments - only the first segment plays

Tags: html, google-chrome, webrtc, getusermedia, web-mediarecorder

I have the following on chrome latest:

```
 var options = { mimeType: "video/webm;codecs=vp8" };
 internalMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(internalStream, options);
 internalMediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function (blob) {
        // put blob.data into an array
        var src = URL.createObjectURL(blobData.segment);
        const $container = $("body");
        const $video = $("<video id='" + blobData.ts + "-" + blob.data.size + "' controls src='" + src + "'></video>").css("max-width", "100%");
        $container.prepend($video);
        // if I stop/start the recorder, I get playable segments here, separated by unplayable mini-segments from onDataAvailable because I call stop right after processing a video.  I can "approximate" desired behavior by doing this and then ignoring blobs that are less than some threshhold to ignore the "dead gap" segments.
 }
 internalMediaRecorder.start(segmentLengthInMs); // every 5s
```

I then compile an array of 5s segments - the blob data is available.  However when I create a URL for each of these segments:

```
 URL.createObjectURL(videoSegment)
```

Only the first video plays.  Why is this?

**UPDATE**

If I stop/start the recorder in `onDataAvailable`, I get playable segments here, separated by unplayable mini-segments from onDataAvailable because I call stop right after processing a video.  I can "approximate" desired behavior by doing this and then ignoring blobs that are less than some threshhold to ignore the "dead gap" segments.  This smells like feet though and I'd like to get proper segmentation working if possible.

Comment: When you did the start/stop method on the dataAvailable event did you experience any performance issues (lagging/crash)? I'm currently using the same method to get individual playable segments but it seems this method makes Chrome crash after a few passes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its expected as per the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/mediastream-recording/#mediarecorder-methods)

> The UA MUST record stream in such a way that the original Tracks can be retrieved at playback time. When multiple Blobs are returned (because of timeslice or requestData()), **the individual Blobs need not be playable, but the combination of all the Blobs from a completed recording MUST be playable.**

The resulted blobs are not raw video data, they are encoded with requested MIME type. So you need merge all the blobs in correct order, to generate a playable video file.

```
var options = { mimeType: "video/webm;codecs=vp8" };
var recordedBlobs = [];
internalMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(internalStream, options);
internalMediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function (event) {
    if (event.data && event.data.size > 0) {
        recordedBlobs.push(event.data);
    }
}
internalMediaRecorder.start(segmentLengthInMs); // every 5s

function play() {
   var superBuffer = new Blob(recordedBlobs, {type: 'video/webm'});
   videoElement.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(superBuffer);
}
```

See the [demo](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/record/)

Comment: Thanks Ajay.  What if I want the segments to be individually playable videos?

Comment: What is your use case? If you need live data, directly play the stream. The purpose of recorder is to generate the encoded(compressed) data. If you need only video then render video stream on canvas and take a snap (15 times per second)  and render the snap data on destination canvas.

Comment: Use case is I need to record n second segments of continuous playable video.

Comment: I just tried this superbuffer method to see if it works and the first segment works, but as soon as I reach the second segment, video playback freezes.  Any idea why this would happen?

Comment: You need to wait until recording completes.